# error install basemap on mac

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I follow the setup from this link: http://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/

However, after I finish all the process. I still encounter error trying to import basemap module.
The error message is like the following: 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ImportError: No module named basemap

Thanks!

Comment: What does ``sys.path`` say? Where did matplotlib and basemap get isntalled to?

Comment: @JamesMills I use import sys; print sys.path to checked the package. However, I didn't find the basemap package. How do I add the path to that package? This is part of the path I use /cluster/basemap-1.0.7. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesMills Thanks a lot! I solved the problem. Instead of using "python setup.py", I use python setup.py install on mac. The problem is solved.

Comment: can you add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

If I do:

`import mpl_toolkits
mpl_toolkits.\_\_path\_\_ (there are 2 underscore before and after the word path)`

I have:

`['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits']`

Obviously, the basemap sub-package is NOT present under that directory. So, I add one:

`mpl_toolkits.__path__.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits')`

Now:

`mpl_toolkits.__path__
Out[21]: 
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits']`

Then:

`In [22]: from mpl_toolkits import basemap`

The module baseman started loading but I've got another problem (looking for the geoslib in the wrong path!!) but I think I've made a step in the right direction do solve that issue.

Comment: Thank you! This just saved me a whole lot of time. For some reason something broke with my basemap, and updating the path as you described here was the only way to get it working again.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently add this to my `mpl_toolkits.path`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Mac/Yosemite.  The following worked for me.

1. Built and installed the dependencies libraries (freetype and geos)
2. Built and installed the python code (matplotlib and basemap)

I think there's contention between the mpl_toolkits installed by Apple and those we have just built.  So, I moved the Apple supplied kit and used ours in its place.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
sudo mv mpl_toolkits/ mpl_toolkits.orig
sudo mv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/ .
```

Test suite runs beautifully:

```
cd ~/gnu/basemap/basemap-1.0.7/examples
python test.py
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

copied the *basemap* directory from

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/
```

to

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits/
```

Comment: can you give a more generalized answer?